# Error when utilizing the finalvalue variable in the main program

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number and find itx  x multiple");
        int user_Input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int final_Value;
        for (int i = 1; i < user_Input; i++)
        {
            final_Vaulue = user_Input * i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("your desired number is : {0}", final_Value);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

I instead trying this but again a compilation error saying use of unsigned variable final_Value.

Comment: This is an EXACT duplicate of your other question where you got a bunch of answers that should have answered your question. You've been told over and over that it's simply an uninitialized variable.

Comment: but in that question there was a mistake.. thats why i post thix question

Comment: Then edit the original post. Most SO users don't appreciate reposting the exact same question -- not to mention it being against the rules, especially when it's trivial to solve AND your question has already been answered.

Answer (score 3):

Your final_Value variable is not initialized to anything. If the user inputs 0, the for-loop wont loop so the final_value will never be set to anything. You can initialize final_Value to 0 for instance:

```
int final_Value = 0;
```

Comment: great idea.. im gonna check.. thanx

Comment: thanx christian.. it worked

Comment: can i have u as a friend on facebook

Comment: I'm not on facebook, but if you have questions, the StackOverflow community will surely help. Try to search for questions from other people though, because duplicated questions are not very welcome. However, you may if you like select my answer as the answer to your question. :)

Comment: dear i need to know that why we create classes.. in c#